# Express API to fetch all SQLite elements that match a parameter returns undefined

Tags: javascript, api, express

I have a number of APIs that work exactly as they should and get and post without a problem. However, when I try to fetch all records based on a parameter, I get undefined as a response. What is even more frustrating is if I enter the search string into my browser, I get the expected response.

**API snippet**

```
tilesRouter.param('cardId', (req, res, next, cardId) => {
  console.log('cardId: ', cardId);
  const sql = 'SELECT * FROM tile WHERE card_id = $cardId';
  const values = {$cardId: cardId};
  console.log('param sql: ', sql);
  console.log('param values: ', values);
  db.all(sql, values, (error, tile) => {
    if (error) {
      next(error);
    } else if (tile) {
      console.log('param req:tile: ', req.tile);
      req.tile = tile;
      next();
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(404);
    }
  });
});

tilesRouter.get('/:cardId', (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200).json({tile: req.tile});
});
```

**Util snippet**

```
Bingo.getTiles = card_id => {
  const url = `${baseUrl}/tiles/${card_id}`;

  return fetch(url).then(response => {

    if (!response.ok) {
      return new Promise(resolve => resolve([]));
    }

    return response.json().then(jsonResponse => {
      console.log('jsonResponse: ', jsonResponse); // empty
      return jsonResponse.tiles.map(tile => camelcaseKeys(tile));
    });
  });
};
```

**URL screenshot**

[image: URL screenshot]

Comment: Can You `console.log(url)` in Bingo.getTiles just before return statement?

Comment: I believe I found the problem so I'm going to close the question. Thank you for being prepared to help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like You have a problem with string literal template in Your code. I believe You would like to search tile based on cardId value.

```
tilesRouter.param('cardId', (req, res, next, cardId) => {
  console.log('cardId: ', cardId);
  const sql = 'SELECT * FROM tile WHERE card_id = $cardId';
```

So to inject cardId variable, You have to use template literals:

```
const sql = `SELECT * FROM tile WHERE card_id = ${cardId}`;
```

Note differences:

- Template strings are enclosed by the back-tick (``) character instead of double or single quotes.
- Template strings can contain place holders. These are indicated by the dollar `$` sign and curly braces `{}`

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/template_strings).

Comment: Thanks, this worked. What I still don't understand is why it worked in another piece of code but that's a problem for another day.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is how the parameter is passed. If I hardcode the SQL statement to `'SELECT * FROM tile WHERE card_id = 26'` instead of `'SELECT * FROM tile WHERE card_id = $cardId'`, the process works. I'm going to figure out what I'm doing wrong with the parameter value now I know the SQL statement and API are actually working.

Comment: You can check my answer :)

Comment: Thanks, @KarlR. I'll give it a try as soon as I finish fighting with another problem I'm having: my render function keeps going off like a packet of crackers. I can see another question being posted soon... :)

Comment: When it goes to the problem which You have described here, I am pretty sure that string literal was an issue regarding Your research and my answer should help. When it goes to another problem - SO is waiting :)